# Error with OpenCV 2.4.x with Visual C++ 12

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm developing a image processing using Visual C++ 2013 Update 4 with OpenCV 2.4.x library in Windows 7 x64 SP1.

For the project, I use two configuration, one for x86, another for x64. 
On x86 config, it works fine. However, on x64, it always generate an exception at line:

```
Mat dst = imdecode(buff, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

For the first time calling this line, the output window prints:

```
Unhandled exception at 0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD in AppClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

The next times calling it, the output is:

```
First-chance exception at 0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD in AppClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.
```

I try this in original project:

```
imencode(".jpg", src, buff, vector<int>{CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100});
imdecode(buff, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

and debug. The buff vector is ok after imencode but it give the exception as described above.

I also try to copy these line to a sample project, also the property sheet of original project and use the same input. It's working perfectly for both x86 and x64.

I've tried for OpenCV 2.4.10, 2.4.11, debug and release lib. The problem is the same!

Any help!
Thanks!

Comment: The patterns `0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD` and `0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC` indicate that you are using pointers from uninitialized memory. `First-chance exception at 0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD` comes from trying to access memory at that address, and the paging system (disk swap) sends out this message to see if anyone will handle the page fault.

Comment: I'm sorry for making misunderstanding. Each time program run, that addresses is different so I just use the pattern, not the realistic address.